# Using JMX to monitor Cassandra's disk related failures

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

Cassandra (2.0.7)  has two parameters to configure disk failures policies

- My configuration of /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

  - commit_failure_policy = stop_commit
  - disk_failure_policy=best_effort

What are the JMX attributes that designate commit_log / disks failures?

*(My goal is to monitor situations when the policies were triggered.)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are any other useful MBeans, but the best_effort policy sets org.apache.cassandra.db.BlackListedDirectories.{UnreadableDirectories,UnwritableDirectories} when file system exceptions occur.

Comment: There is also more generic attribute ExceptionCount at "org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageService". Unfortunately, i don't know the cassandra's code base well enough to reason about attributes.